# Binding enum type to a HTML5 range control

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an enum Model and want to assign it to a range control(HTML5). Any idea how this could be done. Here's my sample code:

```
public enum SkillLevel
    {
        Beginner = 1,
        Intermediate,     
        Advanced,
        Professional
    }
```

and I want the SkillLevel to be shown as a slider(type="range") in my view.

Answer (score 0):

You could start off by making this a bit easier by giving all your enums values (e.g. 1-4)

```
public class Enums
{
    public enum SkillLevel
    {
        Beginner = 1,
        Intermediate = 2,     
        Advanced = 3,
        Professional = 4
    }
}
```

And then your min would be 1 and max would be 4.

```
<input id="skillLevel" name="skillLevel" type="range" min="@(int)Enums.SkillLevel.Beginner" max="@(int)Enums.SkillLevel.Professional" step="1" />
```

Your Controller can then accept your form input of type `SkillLevel` and the model binding will do the rest (so a value of 4 on your form will appear in your controller as `SkillLevel.Professional` in your Controller)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Enums.SkillLevel skillLevel)
{

}
```